# Promote an artifact from one repo to another fails using curl command

Tags: curl, jenkins, artifactory

I am trying to promote a `multi configuration` Jenkins build from one repo to another using this curl command:

```
curl -H Content-Type:application/json -X POST -d '{"status":"released","sourceRepo":"repo-promoted","targetRepo":"repo-released"}' http://artifactory/api/build/promote/build.name/144
```

But I get this error:

> **message** Cannot find builds by the name
>   'build.name' and the number
>   '144'.
>
> **description** The requested resource is not
>   available.

The build exists (ie. there's a link to it in the "builds" section).  Any idea what is causing this?  Do I need to specify the configuration label somewhere?

Comment: I'm assuming you used `build.name` here as a placeholder.. what happens if you try a property search with `build.name=<actual build name>`?

Comment: I used actual build name with promoted build number.  The only thing missing was the configuration label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to specify the parent job name, and the promoted build number with the promoted build label (configuration), and to substitute spaces as follows:

```
<parent.job.name>/$PROMOTED_NUMBER%20::%20BUILDMODE=$buildmode,label=$nodeName
```